# .NET MVC Check header before allowing response

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have created a Login system that provides the user with an API-key on successful login. The API key has an access level attached to it.

I am sending the API key in the header with every Ajax request from my front end, however it is no longer sending a correct response.

This is one of my controllers:

```
[AllowCrossSiteJson]
    public class WebOrdersController : Controller
    {
        protected IWebOrdersService _webOrdersService = new WebOrdersService();
        // GET: WebOrders
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [WebOrdersAPIFilter]
        public String GetTotals()
        {
             return _webOrdersService.GetAllTotals();
        }
    }
```

And this is my Filter class:

```
public class WebOrdersAPIFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            IAccountsService _accountsService = new AccountsService();
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Authority", "*");

            var rawUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;
            var routeArray = rawUrl.Split('/');

            var route = routeArray[0].ToLower();

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(route))
            {
                route = routeArray[1].ToLower();
            }

            var headers = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers;

            // Ensure that all of your properties are present in the current Request
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(headers["Authority"]))
            {
                var apiKey = headers["Authority"];
                //GET API LEVEL
                int accessLevel = _accountsService.CheckAPIKey(apiKey);

                if(route == "weborders" && (accessLevel != 1 || accessLevel != 3 || accessLevel != 6))
                {
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("http://localhost/error/unauthorised");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("http://localhost/error/notloggedin");
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

If the user is not logged in, the API Key is not sent in the header, so if it does not exist it is safe to say they are logged out. If they are logged in, The key is sent. I am then getting the access level of they key and comparing it to the route.

I have debugged it and found that the route and accessLevel variables are working correctly however even then it does not return and response and if the IF() statement fails, it is returning the html for the page /error/unauthorised or /error/notloggedin and not actually redirecting.

How can I achieve the functionality i require, to ensure that the user requesting the data is authorised?

Comment: What if you use a `RedirectToRouteResult`

Comment: In the OWIN Startup class, Configuration method, you can add additional authentication validation on IAppBuilder.UseCookieAuthentication. You have access to the logged in user as well as the Request and Response objects. Even if the user is logged in with an unexpired cookie which avoids the login page, the extra validation code still runs on every call to the server